# Automaticaly modifying parameters

Tags: python

> I am running a script by typing `xxx.py param.par` `xxx.py` is
> the python script and `param.par` is the text file where I am
> defining parameters for the script.
>
> In `param.par` I have:

`x=1`
`y=0.1`
`z=10`

> So, after modifying those numbers I am saving `param.par` and
> running the script.
>
> I need to change `x` from 1-10 (step 1) and `y` from 0.1-1
> (step 0.1). Instead of doing all this manually and saving every time
> `param.par` file and then running script is there any option for
> how this can be automatized in python.
>
> Any suggestions or examples are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: `for x in range(x_start, x_stop, x_step):` - for y you might need to scale the value as parameters have to be integer.

Comment: What confuses me is where I need to add this line of the code ... should I create another script .... :)

Comment: you need to run your code that depends on those parameters in 2 loops, one for each parameter that changes.

Answer (score 0):

Define whole `xxx.py` as a function with arguments and run it in 2 `for` loops.

```py
def x(x, y, z):
    # here throw all your xxx.py code

# use your default z param:
z = 10

for x in range(1, 11, 1):
    for w in range(1, 11, 1):
        y = w/10
        x(x, y, z) # you might use print(x(x,y,z)) if you're returning output in the function
```

So afterall you will have every possible combination of `x` and `y` used as argument in your function.

Comment: range requires integer values.

Comment: Fixed by changing iterator to `w` and assigning `w/10` to `y`

Comment: Thanks this probably can work ... in my case there is one potential problem. I do not have access to the code so only I can execute the code and change the .par file (my appology for not mentioning this in the question).

Comment: @user16454053 are you able to read the contents of this file?

Comment: I am not in position to modify xxxx.py only param.par ....

Answer (score -1):

If you want to modify a file, you can use

```py
with open("param.par", "w") as f:
    f.write(<yourstring>)
```

This in combination with a for loop will hopefully solve the issue.